# Jersey Client with Client Filter

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am using Jersey Client.

```
Client client = Client.create();
client.addFilter(new Myfilter());
// do some other things
```

And Myfilter Class

```
public class Myfilter extends ClientFilter {

    public ClientResponse handle(ClientRequest cr) {
         System.out.println("called");
         ClientResponse resp = getNext().handle(cr);
         return resp;
    }
}
```

I am not able to call handle method of Myfilter. Can anybody help me out in this?

Answer (score 2):

This [Article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0540/ug_restbc-filters_p/index.html) explains how to add a filter for jersey client.

Hope it helps

P.S : in case you forgot to add it to your web.xml

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>your.package.ClientFilter</param-name >
</init-param>
```

Example

```
@Override
    public ClientResponse handle(ClientRequest request) throws ClientHandlerException {
        request.getHeaders().putSingle(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        return getNext().handle(request);
    }
```

Comment: i am not using netbeans...m using eclipse or any GUI tool to configure  filter

Comment: its not about the IDE/GUI . that helps in knowing the approach

Comment: i created filter but can u tell how to call handle method

Comment: also in your handle method you need to return response

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22912/discussion-between-techexchange-and-lucky-boy)

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple example (using jersey-client version 1.x) which results in printing "called" to console:

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.*;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.ClientFilter;

public class JerseyClientFilterExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = Client.create();
        client.addFilter(new MyClientFilter());
        client.resource("http://google.com").get(ClientResponse.class);
    }
}

class MyClientFilter extends ClientFilter {
    @Override
    public ClientResponse handle(ClientRequest cr) throws ClientHandlerException {
        System.out.println("called");
        return getNext().handle(cr);
    }
}
```